# Stack name 'awseb-e-kmcirsxf7y-imutableStack' aborted operation.'CREATE_FAILED' Reason:The resorce failed to create:[AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition]

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

This is an error message from AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment when the environment is updating and causing deployment failed.

```
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-kmcirsxf7y-immutable-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].
```

I have checked the instance spec,AWS ServiceRole permission to create stalk.
Intresting factor is another environment deployed successfully with the same configuration within the same aws account. How can i solve this ?